# How to I combine multiple IEnumerable list together

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a class (ClassA) that has a IEnumerable property.  I then has another class (ClassB) that has the same property. They are sharing an interface (InterfaceA).  The ClassB is basically a container class for multiple ClassA's.  How to I implement the property for ClassB.

```
interface InterfaceA
{
    IEnumerable<int> MyInts
    {
        get;
    }
}

class ClassA : InterfaceA
{
    public IEnumerable<int> MyInts
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

class ClassB : InterfaceA
{
    ClassA[] classAs = new ClassA[10];
    public IEnumerable<int> MyInts
    {
        get
        {
            //What goes here ?
            classAs.SelectMany(classA => classA.MyInts);
        }

    }
}
```

I tried using a LINQ select statement but that doesn't work.

Edit:
Looks like I didn't look hard enough.  The answer is here in this question.
[How do I Aggregate multiple IEnumerables of T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063234/how-do-i-aggregate-multiple-ienumerables-of-t)

Edit 2:
Include the example code that worked for me, incase anyone else needs it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Aggregate multiple IEnumerables of T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063234/how-do-i-aggregate-multiple-ienumerables-of-t)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just adding my answer, so this doesn't go unanswered.

classAs.SelectMany(classA => classA.MyInts);

Found this from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063234/how-do-i-aggregate-multiple-ienumerables-of-t).

Answer (score 3):

```
        public IEnumerable<int> MyInts
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (ClassA c in classAs)
                {
                    foreach (int i in c.MyInts)
                    {
                        yield return i;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```